# Closed - How to convert a known MAC address into CBPheripheral identifier?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I'm aware that in iOS, we couldn't able to get the Mac Id of the devices directly. is there any way, so that if I have a MAC id, can I convert that into a identifier, which CoreBluetooth gives.

Here is my usecase : 
I have a know Mac Id coming from the server. So In the list of devices available, I should connect with the device, that have the known Mac Id. Any workaround ? Thanks.

UPDATE : We can't able to do that as its two different complete entity. Sorry for bit beginner question.

Comment: No you can't, unless you maybe reverse engineer the "random" MAC to UUID used by iOS. But if you have control over the device, you can put it into the advertisement data, or a in characteristic value, that could help you identify the correct device to connect to.

Answer (score 1):

Directly using MAC address not possible. But there is way to identify your device , Services discovering UUID.
There is API called

```
- (void)scanForPeripheralsWithServices:(NSArray<CBUUID *> *)serviceUUIDs 
                               options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options
```

example :

```
[self.centralManager 
 scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:DEVICE_INFO_SERVICE_UUID]] 
                        options:nil];
```

Goto for best practice https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice.html

more info :
https://medium.com/@yostane/getting-started-with-bluetooth-low-energy-on-ios-ada3090fc9cc